# Regular expression over a language - slight confusion

Tags: regular-language

[image]

`Alphabet:` **Σ = {0, 1}**

I'm not too sure what this question is asking. I've posted the answer (just so people don't think it's homework - I'm  actually trying to learn these). I'm not quite sure why we have an **|** in the middle of both of these. I understand that we need Σ for the alphabet, but I'm really confused with what the question is asking. A little confused with 0 in the left and 1 on the right but I believe this is to include the alphabet (0, 1).

Really appreciate all the help.

**Edit:** This is not a maths question. Also, the answer is from a book in regards to regular expressions but I don't understand how the author got this answer.

Comment: This is a math question, not programming. Try math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `I'm not too sure what this question is asking. I've posted the answer` -> What ?!?!

Comment: ***alternative?*** I am not sure you interpret the | the way it is meant. This is for sure not a regular expression... :)

Comment: I suspect you're being downvoted because regular expressions, when used in most programming languages, have a much different syntax to this. I believe the notation used here is typically only found in theoretical computer science. I wouldn't know whether that makes the question relevant here or not - I'm still very new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language *L<sub>2</sub>* is comprised of words with letters denoted *w<sub>1</sub>* to *w<sub>n</sub>*, where n >= 3 (i.e. words are 3 letters or more) and the second letter (*w<sub>2</sub>*) matches the last letter (*w<sub>n</sub>*).

Given that your alphabet consists of only two letters, you have two possible forms:

1. The second letter is a 0; so the word will start with either character (represented by Σ), followed by a 0, then an unknown number of other characters (Σ* - the asterisk denotes zero or more), and then the final 0.
2. Or the second letter is a 1; so the word will again start with either character (*Σ*), but then followed by a 1, an unknown number of other characters (*Σ**), and the final 1 again.

When you add these two options together and you have: (Σ0Σ*0) + (Σ1Σ*1)